# JQuery .children returning everything, not just the requested

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get descendants of a div so that I can disable all the Kendo widgets. However when I call .find or .children it seems to be returning everything. Not just the requested type.

My html:

```
<div id="test">
  <div id="sub">
    <select></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
var count = 0;
var kids = $("#test").children("div");
for (child in kids) {
    console.log(child);
    count++;
}
console.log(count);
```

the console output:

```
0
length
prevObject
context
jquery
constructor
init
selector
size
toArray
get
pushStack 
...
getKendoTimezoneEditor
kendoMobileTimezoneEditor
getKendoMobileTimezoneEditor
kendoMobileSwipe
kendoTouch
getKendoTouch
kendoGantt
getKendoGantt
kendoPivotConfigurator
getKendoPivotConfigurator
Total Count : 306
```

Any thoughts? Using Find has the same result.

Comment: You are iterating over the **property names** of the jQuery object, not over elements.

Comment: @FelixKling - so children returns a collection of property names?

Comment: No, `.children`, like many jQuery methods, returns a *jQuery object*. `for...in` iterates over the property names of the given object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @FelixKling - Oh ok. Thanks for the help! I'm only two weeks into this stuff. I have A LOT to learn.

Comment: This question doesn't deserve the downvotes, it's not immediately obvious that for loops work like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of traversing the object properties names as your are doing, you should traverse the elements themselves. You can do this with jquery `.each` which iterates over the selected elements, in this case the elements you saved in kids:

```
$(kids).each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    count++;
})

console.log(count);
```

You can read more about `.each` method here: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Code without an explanation is generally not very helpful.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah saw your comment and didnt want to copy it. Will add it though

Comment: Children returns jQuery, so you don't need to wrap 'kids' in $() to create a new jQuery object. See http://api.jquery.com/children/